# AMPScript function that escapes HTML characters?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm sending an email to a sendable data extension.
We personalize the email using `%%=v(@firstname)=%%`

We want to escape any HTML characters in `@firstname`.

Is there an AMPScript function that does that?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by _HTML characters_?

Answer (score 1):

There's not really a function like this in AMPScript.  You'll have to replace characters with [HTML Entities](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref) manually.  For example:

```
%%=replace(replace(@firstName,">","&gt;"),"<","&lt;")=%%
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid XSS use the example below:

`URLEncode('http://example.com?p=examplé',1,0)`

System returns:
`http://example.com?p%3dexampl%c3%a9`

[**URLEncode**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/urlencode.htm?search_text=url)