# Ampscript not displaying field because of '<' character?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I've set up a rowset and I'm defining a field, all the other fields are rendering fine, except one field and I suspect it is because the values start with '<' and end with '>'.
The value of this field is typically '', I can't really change this as this data is flowing in from an external system.

```
    SET @couponAssociatedToTransac=field(@row,"coupon_associated_to_transactions")
```

And then I'll try to render it likeso:

```
%%=v(@couponAssociatedToTransac)=%%
```

I even ran a simple test and it did not render as well:

```
SET @testvariable='<No Coupon Used>'
%%=v(@testvariable)=%%
```

What's a workaround to displaying this string as it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming this is an HTML-bound script, you're basically creating (invalid) HTML elements, so it simply doesn't get rendered. Change your code to use escaped HTML characters:

```
SET @testvariable='&lt;No Coupon Used&gt;'
```

See the [Character Entity Reference Chart](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref) for various symbols you can use in HTML output.

See also [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/82567/2984) that addresses escaping HTML characters in general. Realistically, you'll want something like:

```
%%=replace(replace(@couponAssociatedToTransac,">","&gt;"),"<","&lt;")=%%
```